# In angularJS, how could I go through the variables in one object and set them equal to another object's variables of the same name?

Tags: angularjs

I feel like this may involve strings and a forEach statement? I'm pretty new to angular, but basically what I would like to do is this:

I have two objects, where every variable in object 1 is in object 2, but object 2 has more variables than object 1. I need to set all the values that the two share to be equal.

My guess would be perhaps going through Object 1 using forEach and setting the names of its variables to a string, then setting Object2.nameOfVariable equal to the item that the iterator is currently on?

This is a mockup that made sense in my head, but I have a poor understanding of forEach, and thus this does not work:

(in a factory)

```
loadValues: function(object1, object2) {
      object1.forEach(item){
        var varName = angular.toString(item);
        object2.varName = item;
      }
      return object1;
    },
```

Comment: Hard to tell eactly what you're trying to achieve. Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically

Comment: Sorry, I'm having trouble describing my goal. Basically, object1 is a subset of object2. I need to set all of the values that object2 has in common with object1 to be equal to object1's values, while maintaining the additional objects that object2 has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop over `object1` and set its values to `object2` values:

```
for (var prop in object1) {
    if (object2.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        object1[prop] = object2[prop];
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked flawlessly, thank you! I was unaware of hasOwnProperty, very handy.